# References on the analysis of "but"

Tags: logic, reference-request

I want to read philosophy papers that analyze the logical connective "but", and contrasts it with "and". I once read a paper that talked about this topic, but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humberstone's epic tome [*The Connectives*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjj0tXLvr3uAhUMG80KHXZtB9UQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.uvic.ca%2Findex.php%2Fpir%2Farticle%2Fview%2F12610%2F3800&usg=AOvVaw1Ew7NZ0r_1jyWBmNMvJnAo) is always a good place to start for such questions. While "but" isn't treated directly, Humberstone does spend a couple pages (674-676) giving references on the topic. [Sweetser 1990](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/from-etymology-to-pragmatics/F1454419128B2D24A372DD0808B51198) and [Rudolph 1996](https://www.degruyter.com/view/title/3830) seem especially interesting on the philosophical/linguistic side of things. On the mathematical side Humberstone says that there isn't as much material but references [Francez 1995](https://doi.org/10.1093/jigpal/3.5.725) and [Meyer/van der Hoek 1996](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02127972), and [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381620/metamathematics-of-buts) provides some further context.